# Rails 5 - has_many through: association and select in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-select, has-many-through

How I can get selected values in select helper with has_many through: association and nested form?

app/models/team.rb

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_users
  has_many :users, through: :team_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team_users, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |a| a['user_id'].blank? }
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_users
  has_many :teams, through: :team_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team_users, :teams, allow_destroy: true
end
```

app/models/team_user.rb

```
class TeamUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team, :user, allow_destroy: true
end
```

app/controllers/teams_controller.rb

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_team, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_team_users, only: [:new, :edit]
  before_action :set_new_team_user, only: [:new, :edit]
  before_action :set_team_users_collection, only: [:new, :edit]

  ...

  # GET /teams/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  ...

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_team
      @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_team_users
      @team_users = @team.team_users
    end

    def set_new_team_user
      @new_team_user = @team.team_users.build
    end

    def set_team_users_collection
      @team_users_collection = User.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] }
    end

    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(
        :name,
        :parent_id,
        team_users_attributes: [:_destroy, :id, :user_id]
      )
    end
end
```

app/views/teams/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@team) do |f| %>
  ...
  <% f.fields_for @team_users do |team_user_f| %>
    <%= team_user_f.select(:user_id, @team_users_collection, { include_blank: true }, class: 'form-control custom-select', style: 'width:auto;') %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This generates the following error:

> `undefined method 'user_id' for #<TeamUser::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f90a13a3f70>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have your arguments wrong in the `select` method:

```
<%= team_user_f.select(:team_user, :user_id, @team_users_collection, { include_blank: true }, class: 'form-control custom-select', style: 'width:auto;') %>
```

See if that works

Comment: This generate error: `wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1..4)`